# Installing tensorflow==2.7.0 in Colab

Tags: tensorflow, installation, google-colaboratory

unable to install tensorflow==2.7.0 in Google Colab

## install tensorflow

!pip install tensorflow==2.7.0

## Results

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.7.0 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems that Google Colab updated it's Python version to 3.10.X in the last few days and thus also pip was updated and many dependencies can not be found.

I downgraded the Python version in my Colab Notebook manually and reconfigured pip (following this guide: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.datasciencelearner.com/change-python-version-in-google-colab-steps/amp/).

Now it is working fine again!